# \tag throwing errors inside \[...\]

Tags: sharelatex

I have a line of code that has an expression inside display math delimiters \[...\]. I want to tag this expression, but as soon as I add a \tag at the end just before the \] I get missing $ and missing } errors. Does anyone know the right way to use \tag with display math?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: welcome to tex.se! `equation` environment defined by `\[ ....\]` is intended for not numbered equation (as also do all stared math environments version like ˙equation*` and `align*`, `gather*` etc from amsmath). so it (they) not accept `tag`s. if you like to have them, than you should write `\begin{equation} ...\tag{whatever}\end{equation}`.

Comment: What `\tag` are you trying to use?

Comment: @Zarko `\tag` requires `amsmath` and therefore `\[...\]` is completely equivalent to `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`, where `\tag` is legal.

Comment: @egreg, you are right. i forgot to emphasize this. i assume, that op use `asmath` if he use `\tag`.